# MySQL - Select where fields exist, rows, if not insert

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update

I want to do all the following in ONE QUERY:

Given some data Address, City, State, Zip.  I want to see if a User already exists with that data, and if not insert a new record.  If so, just update the date modified on it.

1. `SELECT user_id FROM userInfo WHERE Address = '123 Main ST' AND City = 'New York' AND State='NY' AND Zip = '12345'`
2. If count is greater than 0...
3. `UPDATE userInfo SET modifiedDate = '' WHERE user_id =` **SELECTED user_id**
4. Else If count is 0
5. `INSERT INTO userInfo (Address, City, State, Zip) VALUES ('123 Main ST', 'New York', 'NY', '12345')`

I'd like to point out that the Address and City and State and Zip fields are NOT keys of any type, so REPLACE will not work.  Plus, there is additional data I'd like to add in a different query if it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you cannot. REPLACE is used for inserting or updating and it's the only statement that can do both. But it needs unique keys.

If your filter is not a unique key, you cannot know which of the matching rows should be updated, even if you would write separate statements.

If it *is* a unique key, you should add a unique index on it, and you will be able to use REPLACE.

Long story short: Determine your key and update your indexes.

Comment: is it not possible to run a select and then run an if statement?  you can do it in a stored procedure, but why not in a single query?

Comment: A query is a kind of statement. A stored procedure can contain a serie of statements, amongst which a query. But a query itself cannot be multiple statements, because it is one. A parking garage can contain cars, but a car cannot.

Answer (score 0):

To have the option of running two different queries, you'll need to use a Stored Procedure. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateIfNotExists()
BEGIN
DECLARE the_user_id INT; /* or whatever your data type is */
SELECT user_id
    INTO the_user_id
FROM userInfo 
WHERE Address = '123 Main ST' AND City = 'New York' AND State='NY' AND Zip = '12345'
CASE
    WHEN the_user_id IS NULL INSERT INTO userInfo (Address, City, State, Zip) VALUES ('123 Main ST', 'New York', 'NY', '12345');
    ELSE UPDATE userInfo SET modifiedDate = '' WHERE user_id = the_user_id
END
```

Then just execute the stored procedure (with `CALL sp_UpdateIfNotExists`). You could customize this with parameters and so on, I use these in PHP web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Even for the SELECT to be efficient you will need an index on (State, City, Address). For the data consistency the index should apply UNIQUE constraint.

For partial updates of existing rows there is MySQL specific extention: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

To know the id of the affected existing row you can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)` in the UPDATE clause of the INSERT, and then read the value of the usual LAST_INSERT_ID() or its equivalent.